# Inaccessible external volume from Terminal

Tags: command-line, disk-utility, external-disk, core-storage, raid

I've hit a bit of an odd issue with my TimeMachine/external storage backup solution. Do note that I set it up while Apple was changing filesystem management systems (CoreStorage vs APFS vs OS/Data split), and it's debatable whether I used something sensible.

### The setup

It's an external enclosure that contains 4x4TB disks (`/dev/disk[2-5]`), which are built in two 4TB RAID mirrors striped together (`/dev/disk6`), and a final CoreStorage volume on top (`/dev/disk7`), which hosts my TM backup and Photos library (see the diskutil output down below). Accesses using Finder work fine, though the bandwidth sometimes tanks hard and everything slows down randomly, so in retrospect I'd say that a stacked AppleRAID/CoreStorage monster isn't a recommended configuration.

### The problem

The issue I have is that the volume is utterly inaccessible to anything command-line related. Here are permissions on the hidden `/Volumes` directory (or `/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes`, as I just discovered there's now a 2nd set of symlinks but they give out the same results):

```
$ ls -l /Volumes
total 0
drwxr-xr-x     6 root     wheel   192B Oct 28 15:18 ./
drwxr-xr-x    20 root     wheel   640B Mar 26  2022 ../
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root     wheel     1B Oct 18 17:10 Macintosh HD@ -> /
drwxrwxr-x    21 tiennou  staff   782B Oct 28 15:18 Shack/
```

```
$ ls /Volumes/Shack
ls: .: Operation not permitted
```

In other words, I cannot modify anything on it, `cd` autocompletion doesn't work, `mkdir`, `cp` and `touch` report the same permission error. I can move around directories by looking at names using Finder, and I've used [FSMonitor](https://fsmonitor.com/) to watch what accesses the Finder was doing and using the same path (that's where I got the `/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes` directory).

Yesterday I `rsync`-ed stuff there in a directory I made using Finder for a couple hours, and after stopping it and checking around, that directory is still empty from Finder's perspective, so all that data was somehow sent to `/dev/null`? I didn't check disk usage before starting the copy, so I have no way to know if anything made it on the drive.

### The question

I'm at a loss now. My TM backup looks okay (both backing up and restoring work), Photos sync works too, and Disk Utility reported no issue whatsoever with the `/dev/disk7` drive. I'd even agree with someone telling me that's the cursedest setup they've ever seen and I should start over, but I'd really like to save me the hassle of copying 2TB to start over since there's a TM backup involved. Looking back, if it was possible to ditch AppleRAID entirely and put that whole stack of drive under CS that might have been less convoluted, but it's unclear if CS handles any kind of RAIDy things.

If anyone has any insight, advice, or diagnostics to run, that would be helpful!

---

#### Technical details

```
$ diskutil list

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                 Apple_RAID ⁨⁩                        4.0 TB     disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot ⁨Boot OS X⁩               134.2 MB   disk2s3

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk3
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                 Apple_RAID ⁨⁩                        4.0 TB     disk3s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot ⁨Boot OS X⁩               134.2 MB   disk3s3

/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk4
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:                 Apple_RAID ⁨⁩                        4.0 TB     disk4s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot ⁨Boot OS X⁩               134.2 MB   disk4s3

/dev/disk5 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk5
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk5s1
   2:                 Apple_RAID ⁨⁩                        4.0 TB     disk5s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot ⁨Boot OS X⁩               134.2 MB   disk5s3

/dev/disk6 (external, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:          Apple_CoreStorage                        +8.0 TB     disk6

/dev/disk7 (external, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS ⁨Shack⁩                   +8.0 TB     disk7
                                 Logical Volume on disk6
                                 0956590F-5173-4AD3-B8A9-459A95D4ADDC
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

---

```
$ diskutil ar list
AppleRAID sets (3 found)
===============================================================================
Name:                 lagrange-mirror-1
Unique ID:            37E6D0F0-6A8E-4EBF-8C8E-B76D8FD9B2A7
Type:                 Mirror
Status:               Online
Size:                 4.0 TB (4000443039744 Bytes)
Rebuild:              manual
Device Node:          -
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  DevNode   UUID                                  Status     Size
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0  disk2s2   66A56A8A-2368-4D18-8629-146C788F47FE  Online     4000443039744
1  disk3s2   D188DACC-FC30-4326-864D-A9E78E9A2190  Online     4000443039744
===============================================================================
===============================================================================
Name:                 lagrange-raid
Unique ID:            1BD3A301-EA5B-46CC-806A-8BCCD7ADA450
Type:                 Stripe
Status:               Online
Size:                 8.0 TB (8000886013952 Bytes)
Rebuild:              manual
Device Node:          disk6
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  DevNode   UUID                                  Status     Size
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0  -none-    37E6D0F0-6A8E-4EBF-8C8E-B76D8FD9B2A7  Online     4000443006976
1  -none-    DDC6E853-7F0F-4EB8-981B-AFBA900674AE  Online     4000443006976
===============================================================================
===============================================================================
Name:                 lagrange-mirror-2
Unique ID:            DDC6E853-7F0F-4EB8-981B-AFBA900674AE
Type:                 Mirror
Status:               Online
Size:                 4.0 TB (4000443039744 Bytes)
Rebuild:              manual
Device Node:          -
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  DevNode   UUID                                  Status     Size
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0  disk4s2   F6ED3C8E-DFB1-4EAE-AFF2-48C2B62794FF  Online     4000443039744
1  disk5s2   2835A8EC-916C-4C26-96DF-C8334E06D40E  Online     4000443039744
===============================================================================
```

---

```
$ diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (2 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 4BDE5FCB-C0A8-46DC-B05D-C55A6C47E8AD
|   =========================================================
|   Name:         lagrange
|   Status:       Online
|   Size:         8000886013952 B (8.0 TB)
|   Free Space:   533688320 B (533.7 MB)
|   |
|   +-< Physical Volume 1BD3A301-EA5B-46CC-806A-8BCCD7ADA450
|   |   ----------------------------------------------------
|   |   Index:    0
|   |   Disk:     disk6
|   |   Status:   Online
|   |   Size:     8000886013952 B (8.0 TB)
|   |
|   +-> Logical Volume Family E35DD92B-913B-433E-8D1B-8087F646D3BF
|       ----------------------------------------------------------
|       Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
|       Encryption Status:       Unlocked
|       Conversion Status:       Complete
|       High Level Queries:      Fully Secure
|       |                        Passphrase Required
|       |                        Accepts New Users
|       |                        Has Visible Users
|       |                        Has Volume Key
|       |
|       +-> Logical Volume 0956590F-5173-4AD3-B8A9-459A95D4ADDC
|           ---------------------------------------------------
|           Disk:                  disk7
|           Status:                Online
|           Size (Total):          8000000000000 B (8.0 TB)
|           Revertible:            No
|           LV Name:               Shack
|           Volume Name:           Shack
|           Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
|
[snip]
```

Comment: I don't want to insult your intelligence by asking this quesiton, but is `Terminal` allowed "Full Disk Access" in the "Privacy/Security" settings? It's kinda new.

Comment: It's a good point, I hadn't thought of that. I actually just deleted that whole stack and started over, and in the process of freeing some space at point I got a complaint from `tmutil` about needing to do that (I made my own helper script that prunes old backups automatically and uses `tmutil machinedirectory`). But even with that enabled, navigating the drive wasn't really working, unless you used direct paths. I've been able to rsync my Photos library somewhere save, rebuilt the RAID with an APFS container on it, and TM will just have to do its thing again ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Thanks for the hint!